# creating simple bar chart from css and php

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have this problem which Im really struggling with, in theory it should be simple enough, yet i fail to correctly implement it. Perhaps my logic is wrong in approaching this...?

**The Challenge**

I have  a simple web app where users vote who will win a sporting event in a tournament, each round has many matches up to 8.

example some users vote:

- **Match 1 round 2:** *5 users voted liverpool* to win, *3 users selected Manu* to win
- **Match 2 round 2:** *3 Users voted for Arsenal* to win, *5 users voted for Chelsea*

and so on

:

**What I want to do**

I want to display the number of votes for each team in each match in a simple css bar chart

something like this:

[image]

**My Implementation**

I have 2 tables 1 for the events, called `events` and the other table is for recording the votes called `multiple_picks`

*Consider the following query*

(Note `pickNr` **refers to the number of votes a team received**)

```
SELECT multiple_picks.pick, multiple_picks.round_game_nr, COUNT(multiple_picks.round_game_nr) as pickNr ,events.event_id, events.team1, events.team2, events.round, events.tournament
            From multiple_picks
            JOIN events
            ON multiple_picks.event_id = events.event_id
            WHERE multiple_picks.round = '$round' AND multiple_picks.tournament ='$tour'
            GROUP BY pick
            ORDER BY round_game_nr
```

The Query Produces the following result

[image]
**IMPORTANT TO NOTE**

1.As can be seen from the table every 2nd row is a new game!

2.Also 15 players have entered the pool so each match equates to 15 votes

**My Logic**

- Get number of votes for Team A & Team B in each match
- Make percentage of votes for Team A & Team B in each match example (`Highlanders = (9/15)*100 = 60%`)
- Display each match percentage in a `div` - `div` for team 1 `<div style="width:'.$t1Votes.'; height:25px; float:left">`

`DIV` for team 2 `<div style="width:'.$t2Votes.'; height:25px; float:right">`

**My Execution**

```
 $sql    = "SELECT multiple_picks.pick, multiple_picks.round_game_nr, COUNT(multiple_picks.round_game_nr) as pickNr ,events.event_id, events.team1, events.team2, events.round, events.tournament
            From multiple_picks
            JOIN events
            ON multiple_picks.event_id = events.event_id
            WHERE multiple_picks.round = '4' AND multiple_picks.tournament ='Super Rugby'
            GROUP BY pick
            ORDER BY round_game_nr";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        //get vars
        $rgm = $row['round_game_nr']; //not important for example
        $t1 = $row['team1']; //team 1
        $t2 = $row['team2']; //team 2
        $pick =$row['pick']; //selected team
        $pickCount = $row['pickNr']; //number votes

        $t1 = $pick;
        if($pick == "Draw"){
            //skip draws for now
        }
        else if($t1 =$pick ){
            echo'<div id="container">';//opem container
            $percentage1 = ($pickCount / 15) * 100;
            echo'<div class="t1" style=" float:left; height:25px; background-color:red; width:'.$percentage1.'%">'.$pick.'</div>';  
        }//else if
            else if($t1 != $pick){
                $percentage2 = ($pickCount / 15) * 100;
                echo'<div class="t2" background-color:green; style=" float:right; height:25px;  width:'.$percentage2.'%">'.$pick.'</div>';
                echo'</div>';//container
                echo'<div style="clear:">';
            }//else if

    }//while
```

**MY Problem**

This is how part of the end result looks, which is kinda right but it never gets to the 2nd `if statement else if($t1 != $pick)` , thus, the `container div` never gets closed...so I must have a logical error!

[image]

[image]

**Thank you very much for taking the time to read, any help appreciated.**

**Side Note:** Please don't scrutinise me for using depreciated `mysql_query()` statement, I started the "program" this way, so I might as well finish it this way and then start changing it from the start

Comment: where is the html code?

Comment: @freestock.tk I have uploaded part of HTML output on an image above, for now i'm just doing the chart testing on a blank page, with the php generating the HTML output

Comment: Few things I can see, you're assigning `$t1 = $pick` before your if statements. On your first `else if` you're assigning the `$t1` variable instead of doing a comparison `$t1 == $pick`, which will always evaluate to true because of the initial assignment of `$t1 = $pick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a few issues but you mostly had it. Percentage only needs to be calculated once as each loop is a new entry. You were assigning `$t1 = $pick` which means that the last `else if` was never going to be reached. Also you had the `background-color: green` outside of the style bracket, so it wasn't rendering the background colour.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //get vars
    $rgm = $row['round_game_nr']; //not important for example
    $t1 = $row['team1']; //team 1
    $t2 = $row['team2']; //team 2
    $pick = $row['pick']; //selected team
    $pickCount = $row['pickNr']; //number votes

    // Since it's looping for each entry you only need to calculate the total percentage once
    $percentage = ($pickCount / 15) * 100;

    if($pick == "Draw") {
        //skip draws for now
        continue;
    }
    else if($t1 == $pick ) {
        echo'<div id="container">';//opem container
        echo'<div class="t1" style=" float:left; height:25px; background-color:red; width:'.$percentage.'%">'.$pick.'</div>';  
    }//else if
        else if($t1 != $pick) {
            echo'<div class="t2" style="background-color:green; float:right; height:25px;  width:'.$percentage.'%">'.$pick.'</div>';
            echo'</div>';//container
            echo'<div style="clear:">';
        }//else if

}//while
```

Comment: awesome thank you so much!, for the help and advice!